SSL CONNECTION ERROR- Dotmim sync httpresponse
I have Implemented the dotmim.sync nuget package to sync the data from clent to server and server to client db
my client site uses a self signed certificate and the data is stored in sqlite db
My server site uses a ssl certificate which is valid and is obtained from Certificate Authority with a proper domain..
Please help. my both sites are hosted with port 443 (https).
When i try to sync the data using dotmim.sync , i get the below error:
Dotmim.Sync.HttpResponseContentException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
at Dotmim.Sync.Web.Client.HttpRequestHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpClient client, SyncContext context, String baseUri, Byte[] data, HttpStep step, ISerializerFactory serializerFactory, IConverter converter, Int32 batchSize, SyncPolicy policy, CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress1 progress)
